# Get contacts of a group using google people api

Tags: google-people-api

So far, the existing questions and answers have not helped me.
I am trying to get the online "try this API" to work for me.
people.connections.list and contactGroups.get work for me.
However, I can not find a way to get a list of contacts for a given group.
It seems like this should be simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

1. Use [contactGroups.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/get) and specify a **non-zero** `maxMembers` parameter.
2. List the array `memberResourceNames[]` from the returned `ContactGroup` object.

```
{
  "resourceName": string,
  "etag": string,
  "metadata": {
    object (ContactGroupMetadata)
  },
  "groupType": enum (GroupType),
  "name": string,
  "formattedName": string,
  "memberResourceNames": [
    string
  ],
  "memberCount": integer,
  "clientData": [
    {
      object (GroupClientData)
    }
  ]
}
```

3. Use [people.getBatchGet](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/getBatchGet) using the retrieved resource names.

---

I did a contactGroups.list first.
For your step 1. I had to set the resourceName = contactGroups/hex value from the list
The output does not look like yours

> ```
> {
>   "resourceName": "contactGroups/443...",
>   "etag": "k+...,
>   "metadata": {
>     "updateTime": "2020-11-08T15:29:59.193Z"
>   },
>   "groupType": "USER_CONTACT_GROUP",
>   "name": "Tennis",
>   "formattedName": "Tennis",
>   "memberCount": 46
> }
> ```

EDIT: The memberResourceNames array only appears if you specify >0 on maxMembers parameter.

Comment: Changing the maxMembers gave me the memberResourceNames. I think I can figure it out from here. Thanks